# How to use CoreLocation in iOS8/ios9?

Tags: ios

I have programmed a project which use CoreLocation. In this project, I designed a button to get location. However it has no reaction when I click. Someone said it had changed in iOS 8. And I do what he said. But it did't work. Here is my git link: https://github.com/dwjdwj1216/MyLocations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this in your CurrentLocationViewController, getLocation Method change like this:-

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setDelegate:self];
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9) {
   _locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
}
[locationManager setDistanceFilter:10.0f];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

Comment: I found the problem in my project. I think the instance variable named _locationManager have't initialized in the initWithCoder . Is any problem in my initWithCoder ? I put the initialization of _locationManager to getLocation. Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
To Get Current Location, Follow step..
```

First Set Two lines in .Plist File

> NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription       : Allow location
>
> NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription    : Allow location

```
//  AppDelegate.h
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@property (nonatomic,retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

#import "AppDelegate.m"
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self getCurrentLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocatin delegate && Location Methdos

-(void)getCurrentLocation {
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    // To calculate loaction on 500 meters

    /* CLLocationDistance kilometers = 0.5 1000.0; //user will be notified when distance is changed by 40km from current distance
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kilometers; */
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER)
    {
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
#endif
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    //NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        [self getCurrentCountry];
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)aManager didFailWithError:(NSError *)anError {
    switch([anError code])
    {
        case kCLErrorNetwork: // general, network-related error
        {
        }
            break;
        case kCLErrorDenied:{
        }
            break;
        default:
        {
        }
            break;
    }
}

-(void)getCurrentCountry {
    CLGeocoder *geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:locationManager.location
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0)
                        {
                            NSLog(@"Current country: %@", [[placemarks objectAtIndex:0] country]);
                            NSLog(@"Current country code: %@", [[placemarks objectAtIndex:0] ISOcountryCode]);

                            NSLog(@"CountryCode=%@",GetContryCode);

                            SetContryCode
                            setBoolForCountryCode(YES);
                            NSLog(@"CountryCode=%@",GetContryCode);
                        }
                   }];
}
```

Comment: I found the problem in my project. I think the instance variable named _locationManager have't initialized in the initWithCoder . Is any problem in my initWithCoder ? I put the initialization of _locationManager to getLocation. Then it works.

Comment: ok. great.. please upvote answer, if it's helps you. keep coding friend. @戴王炯